# RCP Part Toolbar Handled Tool Item removal

Tags: rcp, e4, descriptor

I seem to have a problem with removing parts programatically, which contain a toolbar.

I create the parts with the following commands:

```
final MPart newPart = partService.createPart("rcpcan.partdescriptor.signalmapping");
partStack.getChildren().add(newPart);
partService.activate(newPart, true);
newPart.setVisible(true);
```

The Partdescriptor looks like this:

[image]

The Problem occurs when I remove those parts created with the partdescriptor.
Heres the code for removing those parts:

```
final MPart inactivePart = (MPart) name, application);
final MElementContainer<MUIElement> parent = inactivePart.getParent();
parent.getChildren().remove(inactivePart);
inactivePart.setToBeRendered(false);
partService.hidePart(inactivePart, true);
```

As soon as I remove one part, all other Parts get one more HandledToolItem added. That's for each Part that is created by the PartDescriptor. To show you what I mean I have some screenshots.

Before removal:

[image]

After Removal:
[image]

Maybe you guys have some idea why this occurs. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `hidePart` already does the remove from the parent and the setToBeRendered(false). You may be confusing it by duplicating that code.

Comment: If all you want to do is show and hide a part you only need to call the EPartService showPart and hidePart, nothing else.

Comment: Thanks guys, this seemed to be the problem